# How do I identify the file system used on a partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, cross-platform

Let's say I have a disk which has undergone corruption and I can't boot it anymore.

How can I identify out the file system that has been used for the disk partition in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Linux system you could use [**Gpart**](http://www.brzitwa.de/mb/gpart/index.html) to scan your disc and guess your partitions.

A live CD version that contains this tool [can be found here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

You could download one of the many Linux Rescue ISO images, burn it to a CD, and boot from it. It surely will have this tool or another similar one, better check before downloading.